# How can I unmount a s3fs mount as a normal user?

Tags: mount, fstab, unmount, fuse

I use S3 a ton. I have over 40 or so buckets floating around between clients. I like the fact that I can list them in /etc/fstab and that they just work. For reference here is one of the buckets.

> coteyrnet /mnt/S3/coteyrnet fuse.s3fs _netdev,use_cache=/tmp,use_rrs=1,allow_other,noauto,users 0 0

It mounts fine, but I am having one heck of a time unmounting it.

The first problem is:

`umount: /mnt/S3/coteyrnet mount disagrees with the fstab`

The relevant part of mtab is:

`s3fs /mnt/S3/coteyrnet fuse.s3fs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,user=coteyr 0 0`

When running mount with no arguments it reports the mount as:

`s3fs on /mnt/S3/coteyrnet type fuse.s3fs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,user=coteyr)`

In addition to that, if I `sudo umount /mnt/S3/coteyrnet` I always get

`umount: /mnt/S3/coteyrnet: device is busy.

  (In some cases useful info about processes that use

  the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))`

`lsof | grep coteyrnet` never returns anything of value, nor does fuser.

**My goal is to get user unmounting working.**

The inability to mount via sudo has been resolved. By using the  "use_cache" setting the files were actually open, but not under the mount point. This is a caveat to that option.  The mount point files are closed but the files were not yet transferred to S3. By waiting "a while" and trying again, sudo can unmount.

Comment: you can get a list of opened files under /mnt/S3/coteyrnet by using `lsof +D /mnt/S3/coteyrnet` and try to close them.

Comment: There are no open files returned

Comment: OK that is odd, after running that command it unmounted fine (using sudo not as a user). Going to look into something.

Comment: Updated the question. `sudo unmount` now works fine. It was just an "issue" with the s3fs layer and how it handled caching. I do not want to remove that part of the question because I think others will stumble across it. I also don't want to put it in as an answer because it doesn't solve the primary problem of unmounting as a user.

Comment: I am surprised that no body else has a problem like this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After working with dpb, we have determined that the issue is a bug and not a lack of knowledge or configuration (it can't be fixed by us)

[Issue 309](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/issues/detail?id=309) has been filed with s3fs maintainers.

Comment: dpb's answer was most helpful, but unfortunately the fix was file a bug report, and not modifying the fstab entry.

Comment: link is now broken

Answer (score 0):

I think /etc/fstab needs the option `user`.  Right now you said you have:

```
s3fs /mnt/S3/coteyrnet fuse.s3fs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,user=coteyr 0 0
```

Trying changing that `user=coteyr` to just `user`.  That works for me.  When I tried to specify the user with `=`, it was essentially ignored.

See the following output for an example:

```
dpb@helo:crash$ mount /mnt/foo
dpb@helo:crash$ umount /mnt/foo
dpb@helo:crash$ grep /mnt/foo /etc/fstab
/dev/vgdata/lvol0 /mnt/foo ext4 defaults,user 0 2
dpb@helo:crash$
```

#### Alternate Solution

If this fails, or if you want an alternate approach.  You can set up a sudo rule that allows mounting and unmounting without a password for certain mounts.  Some would claim this is a safer approach, but I'm no security guru.

#### More specifics for fuse.s3fs

It appears for umount as a non superuser to succeed, it needs to match what is shown by the mount command.

In this case, fstab would need to look like

```
s3fs   /mnt/S3/coteyrnet  fuse.s3fs  <options> 0 0
```

But, I think you still need a way to specify your unique bucket.  Perhaps try:

```
s3fs#coteyrnet  /mnt/S3/coteyrnet  fuse.s3fs  <options> 0 0
```

That may be enough to trick mount (I've seen that before in a couple places, and now I'm starting to realize why)

Comment: The alternate solution is a no go. I don't really want to have to sudo every time I unmount I can do that now. I will give the primary solution a try and let you know.

Comment: I still get `umount: /mnt/S3/coteyrnet mount disagrees with the fstab`

Comment: also /etc/fstab has the users flag, mtab has the user=coteyr flag

Comment: ah, thx about mtab/fstab missed that.  Still, is it 'users' or 'user' in fstab?  Also, did you unmount everything and fix /etc/fstab, then try to mount/unmount?

Comment: users is what I have in fstab, I will give just user a try. Yes I did full  unmount and mount of everything except /

Comment: OK -- I also tried `users` which I have seen on the net in places, and it doesn't work.  The fstab manpage mentions only `user` plain.

Comment: Same error, fstab is: `coteyrnet /mnt/S3/coteyrnet fuse.s3fs _netdev,use_cache=/tmp,allow_other,noauto,default_acl=public-read,user 0 0` mtab is: `s3fs /mnt/S3/coteyrnet fuse.s3fs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,user=coteyr 0 0`

Comment: Can you update your question with the result of a `mount` command when the filesystem is mounted (just the relevant line)?  I think you need to tweak the fstab to agree with exactly what mount thinks it is (down to trailing slashes even).

Comment: Added the data to the question `s3fs on /mnt/S3/coteyrnet type fuse.s3fs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,user=coteyr)`

Comment: Check out the latest... It certainly has *something* to do with that.  That might give you enough to experiment with.

Comment: Don't understand the comment. But I am downloading from svn now

Comment: Sorry, I mean, checkout my latest update on my answer

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6553/discussion-between-coteyr-and-dpb)